# What's the different use case of minus vs minusElement?

Tags: kotlin, collections

In Kotlin collection, we could remove an element using `minus` and `minusElement`

```
val a = listOf("a", "b", "a").minusElement("b")
val b = listOf("a", "b", "a").minus("b")
```

When check `minusElement`, it is essentially `minus`

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.minusElement(element: T): List<T> {
    return minus(element)
}
```

What are their differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plusElement` and `minusElement` are synonyms for `plus` and `minus` with one element and are provided as a workaround for a situation when overload resolution cannot choose the desired overload of `plus` or `minus`.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9992#focus=streamItem-27-1283874.0-0 for details.